# Como eu escolho o escopo certo para um bean?

Tags: java, jsf, escopo-de-variáveis

Pelo que andei estudando, sei que existem vários escopos para beans:

```
@RequestScoped
@ViewScoped
@FlowScoped
@SessionScoped
@ApplicationScoped
```

Qual é a função de cada um? Como eu devo escolher corretamente o escopo do meu bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença é basicamente na duração de cada um.

`@RequestScoped` Nasce e morre após cada solicitação, nenhum estado é guardado. Deve ser utilizado em páginas que só enviam dados para visualização e não tem ação posterior que dependa destes dados no backend, por exemplo, listagens;

`@ViewScoped` Nasce após cada abertura de página, e morre assim que o uma mudança na URL do contexto acontece. Deve ser utilizado em casos onde a edição de algum dado acontece e os beans no backend devem ficar vivos para que possam ser salvos posteriormente;

`@FlowScoped` É basicamente o mesmo do `@ViewScoped` mas não finaliza com a troca de páginas, você pode definir um grupo de páginas que compartilham o mesmo escopo, e acabam em determinado ponto. Pode ser utilizado para cadastros que perduram por mais de uma página por exemplo;

`@SessionScoped` Nasce assim que uma session é estabelecida com o cliente e o bean em questão é requisitado, morre assim que a session é finalizada. Este bean tem uma duração muito grande e não deve ser utilizado na maioria dos cenários. Deve ser utilizado apenas para guardar informações de sessão do usuário que devem perdurar durante mais tempo;

`@ApplicationScoped` Nasce assim que é solicitado pela primeira vez na aplicação, dura enquanto ela estiver viva e é compartilhado entre os vários clientes. Deve ser utilizado para efetuar coisas no contexto da aplicação, como armazenar uma quantidade de clientes logados (é um exemplo idiota, mas só pensei neste agora);